# Growing random trees on a lattice $\rightarrow$ Voronoi diagrams

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes, discrete-geometry, random-graphs, trees

Imagine growing trees from $k$ seeds on a square $n \times n$ region
of $\mathbb{Z}^2$.
At each step, a unit-length edge $e$ between two points of
$\mathbb{Z}^2$ is added.
The edge $e$ is chosen randomly among those that have one endpoint
touching an existing tree and the other endpoint not touching
any tree.  Edge $e$ then extends the tree $T$ it touches, maintains
$T$ a tree, and does not join to another tree.
The process is repeated until no such edges remain.
Here is a view of (a portion of) the trees grown from three seeds:

                   
[image: Growing Trees]

I expected the trees to intertwine and tangle with one another
as they grew,
but instead they appear to be approximating the Voronoi
diagram of the seeds.
Here is an example (of which the above is a detail)
of $k=10$ trees grown within a $100 \times 100$ square:

     
[image: Packed Trees]

I have overlaid the Voronoi diagram of the seeds.

My primary question is:

> **Q1**. Is it known that a tree-growth process like
>   mine approximates the Voronoi diagram in some sense?

Short of this, I would like to correct my faulty intuition:

> **Q2**. Why do the trees not entangle more significantly
>   where they meet?

Finally:

> **Q3**. Are there any results known on the structure of
>   the individual grown trees?  For example, their expected height, perhaps
>   as a function of their Voronoi region shape?
>   (Not surprisingly, the tallest tree ($h=110$) above is the mauve one 
>   with root $(61,41)$ that encompasses the upper right corner.)

Although the book *Percolation* has a chapter on 
"Random Voronoi Percolation,"
I have not been successful in matching their models to mine
closely enough to draw any definite conclusions.

                   
[image: Bollabas]

Thanks for any pointers to relevant literature!

Comment: Spanning forests on $\mathbb Z^2$ are in bijection with domino tilings on $\frac{1}{2}\mathbb Z^2$, so it seems like this can also be transformed into a question about liquid/gaseous regions of the corresponding dimer model. Perhaps the work of Kenyon-Okounkov is relvant?

Comment: Great question by the way!

Comment: Two questions. 1. Do the unit length edges you add have to be horizontal or vertical? 2. How is the first edge added for a given seed? Should the seed be one of its endpoints or should it just lie on it somewhere?

Comment: @Vinayak: Yes, because the edges connect points of the lattice, only horizontal and vertical edges are unit-length.  The seed is a point of the lattice, and the first edge has one endpoint at a seed (obscured in my images by the outline of the seed).

Comment: Might I suggest a more focused experiment which might help pin down one "universality class"?  Go with just two seeds placed vertically from each other (though different "slopes" are also interesting) and study the width of the interface between them as a function of the distance between them. I will boldly guess that the width grows as a power law with an interesting exponent, which might give a clue as to what kind of random curve the interface is limiting onto e.g. a percolation interface or SLE, diffusion front / gradient percolation type thing, or something else entirely.

Comment: Also, do you mind sharing the code you used to make these pictures? I would love to experiment with your process as well!

Comment: What a lovely question, the liquid/gaseous regions work does seem relevant. A quick thought, given the way that the tress grow the taxi driver metric on \mathbb{Z}^2 is perhaps more appropriate for the Voronoi tiling. 

With this metric the probability of a tree reaching a certain point should be a function of distance. This might give you a window into what is happening at the boundary. As another commentator mentioned looking at how the trees change with distance and just 2 seeds might also help.

Comment: Maybe an even easier starting point: what can be said about the process with just a single seed? It seems to be different from the other models of growing trees that I've been able to find, e.g. http://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevLett.68.2329 which has connections to the loop erased random walk of Lawler http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop-erased_random_walk

Comment: @jc: Great suggestions! I will work at preparing a "releasable" version of the code (might take some time).  

Comment: If you want it more "tree-like" with entangling branches, change your probability distribution slightly, e.g. weight edges away from the root slightly more than edges toward the root.  I bet a difference of 5% will show some striking changes.  Gerhard "Go Ask A Plant Person" Paseman, 2017.03.24.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

***Update***:

I think your model for growth has been studied before and goes by the name of the [**Eden growth model**](https://projecteuclid.org/ebooks/berkeley-symposium-on-mathematical-statistics-and-probability/Proceedings-of-the-Fourth-Berkeley-Symposium-on-Mathematical-Statistics-and/chapter/A-Two-dimensional-Growth-Process/bsmsp/1200512888) (See section 4 of the (linked) original paper by Murray Eden).  It seems what is usually studied is a "site addition" model, whereas your model is a "bond addition" model, but I bet the main results will be the same.  I haven't managed to find any recent reviews focusing just on the Eden model yet (and the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eden_growth_model) is sadly very sparse), but I found a description of it in the first pages of [this](http://www.jfgouyet.fr/fractal/fractauk/chapter4.pdf) book chapter of Jean-François Gouyet's ["Physics and Fractal Structures"](http://www.jfgouyet.fr/fractal/fractauk.html).

Famously, the interface of the Eden model was the motivation of [Kardar, Parisi and Zhang](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.56.889) when they defined the universality class now known as KPZ.  [Here's](https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.1596) a nice review of the KPZ universality class by Ivan Corwin.

Thus a lot is (conjecturally) known about this -- in particular, the size of the fluctuations at the perimeter of a single tree with $N$ bonds should scale as $N^{1/6}$ (fluctuations go as radius$^{1/3}$, and I am pretty sure the radius goes like $N^{1/2}$).  Because of this site versus bond addition discrepancy, I haven't found anything about colliding Eden clusters, but I think these ideas can justify that you do get Voronoi cells.  I would be delighted to hear criticism or details from an expert!

---

I don't have anything rigorous to say yet, but some post-facto intuition for **Q2** is as follows.

Consider the case of a single seed.  I'll tell a story about why the growth from a single seed ought to look more or less like a disk with a wiggly edge, rather than something with a lot of branchy and spread-out fingers (like something one gets out of diffusion-limited aggregation, for instance).  If you buy my story, then it should be clearer why there isn't that much "entanglement" at the interfaces between two such growing bodies.

At a given time step $i$, we have a tree $T_i$; let the set of edges that connect $T_i$ to $\mathbb{Z}^2\setminus T_i$ be $G_i$.  Then we may form $T_{i+1}$ by choosing uniformly an edge in $G_i$ and adding it to $T_i$.  So far, this is just your process in different terms.  Here comes some handwaving.  Any "protrusions" on $T_i$ will not get too long, because to grow a subset of $T_i$ which sticks out a significant distance from the rest of $T_i$, we'd have to had chosen edges near the "tip" of this protrusion repeatedly.  But of course the tip of a long protrusion has a small perimeter compared to the sides of the protrusion, and thus it's much more likely that added edges will smooth out any such features instead of extending them.

Why does this end up with something disk-like?  Your process is basically one where you add a "protrusion" to the tree centered somewhere uniformly random on the "boundary".  Thus consider the following "off-lattice" version of your process.  Let $T_0$ be a disk of radius 1 centered at the origin.  $T_i$ is the union of $T_{i-1}$ with a disk centered at a point $p_i$ chosen uniformly from the boundary of $T_{i-1}$.  I hope you can see that this is a stochastic version of [normal evolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_curve) of the boundary.  And as is [well-known to doodlers](https://math.stanford.edu/%7Evakil/files/monthly116-129-vakil.pdf), normal evolution tends towards to circular disks, so "intuitively" a stochastic version will tend to a wiggly disk.  (One complication here is that your process isn't allowed to form loops in the tree, whereas the continuum version I have in mind does).

Comment: OK, I was very sloppy about the effect of the lattice in my last paragraph.  Ori Gurel-Gurevich's answer has convinced me that one needs to be careful about such things, but I still find my analogy to normal evolution (with the Euclidean metric rather than anything else) plausible.

Comment: @jc: Your argument that explains why protrusions are rare is intuitively convincing to me!  When I get a window of free time, I will explore experimentally.

Comment: I wonder if this can be overcome by changing the probability function. An edge whose new endpoint gave lots of new options, or could be chosen in preference to an edge that filled a gap.  

This should give the trees a more branchlike and less blob-like structure and so lead to a lot more entangling. Reading between the lines that seems to be what Joseph might like!

Comment: @Edmund Harriss: That's an interesting line of thought too. You might want to look into Diffusion Limited Aggregation (DLA) processes which form very branchy trees; roughly speaking the probability of adding a site to a DLA process is weighted by the probability of hitting the site with a random walk coming in from infinity, thus the tips end up preferred in such models. 

Comment: Though DLA is well studied, it seems in the usual version with multiple seed sites that is considered, the clusters have a possibility of being connected by a site and then merging, and so I haven't found any works that study how the plane ends up being partitioned into different regions.  See e.g. http://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevB.28.5632

Comment: I will take a look at that, possibilities for interesting patterning here I think. Especially if you can get interesting boundaries.

Comment: @jc: Great sleuthing to uncover the Eden model!  Thanks so much! I have some reading ahead of me now...

Comment: @Joseph O'Rourke: these lecture notes of Kesten explain some more interesting results on the Eden model by relating it to first passage percolation.  It can be hard to keep all these variant models straight, but I believe that your "edge addition" model is the one that maps onto the usual "edge" first passage percolation http://www.springerlink.com/content/q5430m3l3665r52q/

Comment: @jc: Yes, I have been reading about the Eden model, and you are right.  So I guess my model cannot be dubbed the O'Rourke model! :-)

Answer (score 4):

Let me just quickly post one additional figure, a nod in the direction suggested by jc and Edmund.
The left image shows the trees for two sites.  The right image is a 3D depiction of the same
trees, but this time with each node raised in $z$ by its tree height (with the white dots marking
the two roots, at heights 47 and 55).

        
[image: Two Trees]

(I don't have time at the moment to make a more thorough analysis.)

---

Continuing to use this "answer" to supplement the comments, here are four random trees grown from one
seed, each consisting of about 5000 edges:

   
[image: TreeOne]
And here is zoomed detail from the lower right of the brown tree above:

            
[image: Detail]

Comment: Lovely! It's interesting in light of the last sentence of my post that there do indeed seem to be a few small pockets of "uninfected" sites disconnected from the outside in the single trees. Is it feasible to generate many trees with $N$ edges and then to "average" them to see the mean shape? I still have my money on a circular disk of size $N^{1/2}$.

Comment:  There are obvious simple ways, like, sample the radius at N different evenly-spaced angles and average the radius.

Comment: But wouldn't one expect those pockets to be filled by that same color later on, thanks to the untouched points inside them which still allow to go on ?

Comment: @Thomas: Yes, definitely.  My process does not need access "from the outside." You are correct.  I only highlighted the pockets because they relate to a point of jc's.  Also, I just love these tree images as aesthetic objects! :-)

Comment: Joseph: I suggest trying this with the triangular lattice and comparing the results for (essentially) the same initial seeds. See my comments to Ori above.

Answer (score 4):

Q1: It is unlikely that you get the Voronoi diagram. Take a look at "Richardson's growth model" which is closely related (it is your model without the trees). The limit shape there is not a disc, meaning that the model is not rotationally symmetric in the limit, so it's not Voronoi cells.

[Link](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-probability/volume-9/issue-2/The-Shape-of-the-Limit-Set-in-Richardsons-Growth-Model/10.1214/aop/1176994460.full)

- Richard Durrett and Thomas M. Liggett: "The Shape of the Limit Set in Richardson's Growth Model."
  *Ann. Probab.*
  Volume 9, Number 2 (1981), 186-193.

Comment: @Ori: Thanks! I did not know of Richardson's model.  It does approach a convex limiting shape asymptotically, so maybe my process approaches a Voronoi diagram, but under a metric different from the Eulidean metric (as suggested by Edmund).

Comment: I do not quite see how to map Joseph O'Rourke's model to Richardson's growth model. In Joseph O'Rourke's model, one site is added at each time, whereas in Richardson's growth model, many sites are added at each time, depending on the value of $p$. I guess if one lets $p$ decrease as the perimeter of the object grows, you might get a version of Richardson's growth model which is closer to Joseph O'Rourke's model. Is there anything known for that case?

Comment: @jc: I was too hasty in choosing which paper to link to. I think the richardson model in continuous time is more well known - up to small fluctuations in time, this is like adding one edge at a time.

Comment: @Ori Gurel-Gurevich: The papers I have found on continuous time versions of Richardson's model e.g. http://www.springerlink.com/content/j77mv8201u2k8988/ treat a model where sites are infected at a rate $\lambda\cdot$ number of infected neighbors. The rate then just depends on "local" information; whereas in something akin to Joseph O'Rourke's model the next site infected should be chosen uniformly from the set of all uninfected sites adjacent to the infected ones, which is more "global". I could be missing something, though. 

Comment: @jc: the only global effect here is the overall rate in which sites/edges are added. In other words, in the Richardson model, the next edge to be added is distributed uniformly among the edges connecting infected and non-infected sites.

Comment: @Ori Gurel-Gurevich: Thanks for your patience! After looking at Richardson's paper http://journals.cambridge.org/abstract_S0305004100077288 and thinking some more, I understand that the continuous time Richardson's model is the same up to time fluctuations with the Eden model.  However, I haven't found yet a precise reference for the fact that the limit shape for this case is _not_ a disk. Further confusing my search is the fact that Richardson himself discusses something like 9 examples in his paper and it's not clear to me which one is "the" Richardson model.

Comment: This survey page of Durrett's http://www.math.cornell.edu/~durrett/survey/survc1.html seems to suggest that this was proven in Richardson's paper, but in fact the question of whether the limit shape is a round disk is open problem (6) of Richardson's paper.  The main theorem of Richardson's as applied to this particular model seems to be that the limit shape exists and is convex but I can't see how to rule out that it's a round disk.

Comment: I bet with a triangular lattice you'd get equivalence in an appropriate scaling limit. This lattice is isotropic and provides the key advantage of FHP vs HPP lattice gases.

Comment: @jc: Frankly, I remember the result (that it's not a disc), but not where is it from, so I could be mistaken.

Comment: @Steve: equivalence of what? do you mean that you'd get Voronoi cells in the limit, if using the triangular lattice?

Comment: @ Ori: I think it's at least plausible. 
By analogy see, e.g. the HPP and FHP-II/III gases at http://softology.com.au/tutorials/latticegas/hpplga.htm and http://softology.com.au/tutorials/latticegas/fhplga.htm

Comment: @Ori Gurel-Gurevich: Kesten's lecture notes on first passage percolation prove that it's not a disk in sufficiently large dimensions (like $d>10^{6}$) but I haven't found anything else yet.